# Email marked as spam, passes most checks

Tags: email, spam

I've configured a server to send legitimate emails, but almost every test I do results in the email getting flagged as spam on gmail.
I've tried sending direct emails from Horde (we're using cPanel), and also emails from Wordpress and Prestashop, but there's not way to make sure these emails don't get marked as spam.

Here's a test on IsNotSpam: 
http://www.isnotspam.com/newlatestreport.php?email=ins-ttotqfhw%40isnotspam.com

I've read a lot of guides online, according to which at this stage the emails should not get flagged as spam anymore. The only remaining step I see is TLS, but that requires getting a signed certificate.

How can I ensure the legitimate emails our services send don't get marked as spam?

Comment: Try this, http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3aclever-road.com&run=toolpage Email black listing is also common, and people can hook their email servers into any number of these black listing servers.

Comment: We're indeed blacklisted on one server, but surely that doesn't explain on its own the systematic spam labelling on gmail?